# How to specify "this" for typescript generics

Tags: typescript, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to make a utility function to automatically generate pagination for models that are given to it, something like this:

```
import { Model } from 'sequelize-typescript';

async function getPagination<T extends typeof Model>(model: T) {
  const page = 1;
  const limit = 10;
  const data = await model.findAndCountAll({
    limit,
    offset: (page - 1) * limit,
  });

  // Create the pagination object
  const pagination = {}; // some meaningful object

  return {
      data,
      pagination
  };
}
```

but typescript gives me this error:

`The 'this' context of type 'T' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'ModelStatic<Model<unknown, unknown>>'. Type 'typeof Model' is not assignable to type 'ModelStatic<Model<unknown, unknown>>'. Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.`

and by the way my models are defined like this:

```
import { Table, Column, PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Model } from 'sequelize-typescript'

@Table
class CustomModel extends Model implements CustomModel {

  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column
  id!: number;

}
```

Comment: maybe instead of `T extends typeof Model` you should just use `T extends Model`

Comment: @Andrei I've already tried that, in that case the method "findAndCountAll" would not exist on the model anymore.

Comment: how is your model defined, and what do you pass to getPagination?

Comment: @Andrei I've added it at the bottom of my question, and I pass my models ( such as CustomModel ) to getPagination

Comment: ah I see now. the code you provided is ok and shouldn't be fixed. the isue is what you pass to getPagination. could you provide a piece of code where you are doing it?

Comment: @Andrei sadly I can't share the project as it is for my work, the thing is It can be easily fixed if I define `model: any` but I just want to take full advantage of typescript, anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: i believe you can do `await (model as Model).findAndCountAll` or `as any` trick for least possible causualities

Comment: @Andrei it still gives me the same error

Comment: @Andrei obviously setting the type to any fixes the issue, but I'm trying my best to avoid that

Comment: i mean you can break type with `any` in a least possible piece of code. here : `await (model as any).findAndCountAll`. shoud work. was hoping Model type will also be fine, but it seems not

Comment: @Andrei that's true but all I'm using the model for is using "findAndCountAll" on it, so it's basically the same as defining it as `any` at the beginning.

Comment: @Andrei I got it working, in case you are interested, I really do appreciate your help tho <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working,
actually instead of using the generic itself I had to pass the generic, which extends the model to ModelCtor, that's how stuff are done inside sequelize, I guess.

```
async function getPagination<T extends Model>(model: ModelCtor<T>)
```